# Combobox not refreshing after adding items C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, observablecollection

In my main window I have a class where I store all my data in ( called "Measconsettings"). This class ("Measconsettings") contains an ObservableCollection "DeviceDefinitionList" of an other class "DeviceDefinition"

`ObservableCollection<DeviceDefinition> DeviceDefinitionList`.

When I press a button in my MainWindow a new window is created with datacontex = Measconsettings.

In this new window there is a combobox which ItemsSource is bound to "Measconsettings.DeviceDefinitionList".

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,0" Name="CboDeviceDefinitionList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DeviceDefinitionList}"/>
```

My problem now is that the combobox does not update automaticly when an item is added.

I need to close the new window and press the button again to open it and only then it shows the items in the combobox.

I tried adding `CboDeviceDefinitionList.Items.Refresh();` but it does not work..

Only when I add `CboDeviceDefinitionList.ItemsSource = orgMeasConSettings.DeviceDefinitionList;` right after adding items to the ObservableCollection then they show up right away.

Any ideas or tips on how to properly bind to a combobox? PS: I'm wpf beginner

Comment: You need to implement "INotifyPropertyChanged" on your ObservableCollection then it should work.

Comment: It is updating  if you use CboDeviceDefinitionList.Items.Refresh(); after adding new item to the collection.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev No, but after implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the Measconsetting class it works.

Comment: @manish: `INotifyPropertyChanged` shouldn't be necessary unless the collection is being recreated, instead of modified.

Comment: @Enrico I have just written a simple test project and it worked without INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Enrico Also, the mission on ObservableCollection is this.
it is a collection which is used to notify mostly UI to change in the collection , it supports automatic notification.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev In my answer you can see that instead of assigning a new class to the list, I clear the list and fill it again (this does not break the binding) and it now shows the values in the combobox. I also bound the selected value to a parameter and this required the InotifyPropertyChanged event to be added.

Comment: I know. But you dont need INotifyPropertyChanged. ObservableCollection is supports automatic notification. Thi is what i want to say.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution after implementing INotifyPropertyChanged as suggested by manish.

EDIT: It now works!

```
public class MeasConSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

private ObservableCollection<DeviceDefinition> mDeviceDefinitionList;
private DeviceDefinition mSelectedDeviceDefinition;

    public ObservableCollection<DeviceDefinition> DeviceDefinitionList
    {
        get
        {
            return mDeviceDefinitionList;
        }
        set
        {
            mDeviceDefinitionList = value;
        }
    }

    public DeviceDefinition SelectedDeviceDefinition
        {
            get
            {
                return mSelectedDeviceDefinition;
            }
            set
            {
                mSelectedDeviceDefinition = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedDeviceDefinition");
            }
        }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

}
```

XAML CODE:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,0" Name="CboDeviceDefinitionList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DeviceDefinitionList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDeviceDefinition}"/>
```

CODE for adding item:

```
orgMeasConSettings.DeviceDefinitionList.Clear();
            foreach (DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition in newSettings.DeviceDefinitionList)
            {
                orgMeasConSettings.DeviceDefinitionList.Add(deviceDefinition);
            }

            orgMeasConSettings.SelectedDeviceDefinition = newSettings.DeviceDefinitionList.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @DanPuzey yes it does, added this to the answer now.